# Why the await doesn't block the t2 execution till t1 completes?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

#### How the python await keyword differs from Node js await?

In node js the `await` keywords blocks the execution of next line till the current line is completely resolved or awaited.But in python it continues to run the t2 (*from below example*) before t1 completes.

```
import asyncio
import time
async def heavy():
    print("start computing")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("end computing")
async def compute(x, y):
    print("Compute %s + %s ..." % (x, y))
    await asyncio.sleep(6)
    return x + y
async def print_sum(x, y):
    result = await compute(x, y)
    print("%s + %s = %s" % (x, y, result))
async def main():
    print(f"Starting at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    t1= asyncio.create_task(print_sum(10,20))
    t2= asyncio.create_task(heavy())
    await t1
    await t2 
    print(f"Ending at {time.strftime('%X')}") 
asyncio.run(main())
```

Eventhough t2 called after t1,t2 completes before t1.

#### My questions are:

1. What is the Exact usage of `await` keyword in python? **I have searched for many resources till not clear about it.**
2. What did the system understands that,when it encounters an `await` keyword?
3. How the `main()` method in above code works ? *Feel free to give line by line explanation*

**Please Provide detailed explanation for above Questions . . .**

Comment: `create_task` schedules things with the loop. So when `print_sum` encounters something that can be suspended, `heavy` can begin executing.

Answer (score 0):

`await` simply allows you to write asynchronous calls inline with your other synchronous code -

```
import asyncio

async def add(a,b):
  await asyncio.sleep(1)   # sample async function
  return a + b

async def main():
  t1 = await add(1, 2)       # pauses, returns 3 after 1 second
  print(t1)                  # 3
  t2 = await add(3, 4)       # pauses, returns 7 after 1 second
  print(t2)                  # 7
  print(await add(t1, t2))   # pauses, prints 10 after 1 second

print("please wait...")
asyncio.run(main())

# "please wait..."
# 3
# 7
# 10
```

Comment: Once the t1 hits the sleep or time consuming function it immediately awaits and handle the control to t2 .If sleep ends then event loop pushes the t1 or t2  to execution based on waiting time.Am I understanding correctly ?

Comment: When the program encounters an `await`, the current function is effectively paused. The `await`ed function (or expression) is run, its result (if any) is captured, and the paused function resumes. I updated the example in answer for clarity.

Comment: To be more precise, you can `await` only an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio-awaitables). In the example program, `add(?,?)` returns an `awaitable`, so we can use `await` keyword on it.

Comment: Update the example as your wish